# Find a functions $(f_{n})_{n}$ so that they converge in $L^{\infty}([-N,N])$ but not $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

My idea: Let $f \equiv 1$ and set define $f_{n}\equiv 1_{[-n,n]}$ clearly then for any $N \in \mathbb N$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $n_{0}$ large enough such that $\forall n \geq n_{0}$ it follows that $\vert \vert f_{n}-f\vert \vert_{L^{\infty}([-N,N])}=0$ but equally on $\mathbb R$:

$\vert \vert f_{n}-f\vert \vert_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)}=1$ any $n \in \mathbb N$. Is my idea correct?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to say that if $(f_n)$ converges in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, it must converge uniformly to its punctual limit, which is $f$ in your example. hence, you have a contradiction : it cannot converge in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.